# How to see when a package was installed?

Tags: debian, crunchbang

I installed a package, i forgot when, using synaptic package manager, i want to know the installation date. I don't know how and Google doesn't seem to be helpful helping today.

Comment: In general, do not expect that every feature of a Microsoft Windows system has a correspondence on a Linux system. For future questions: avoid subjective opinions ("billion times better than") and unnecessary comments (if you already have found an answer, you would not have asked here...).

Comment: Also note that the features are often implemented very differently across the various Linux distributions, Debian/Ubuntu use apt/dpkg, Redhat/Fedora use RPM.

Comment: @jofel fine, edited my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Method #1 - dpkg.log

You can look through the /var/log/dpkg.log files but this could be problematic since these files are rotated by `logrotate` and can get deleted over time. So if it's something recent you can look to these files:

#### Example

```
$ ls -lt /var/log/dpkg.log*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 378458 Oct  6 11:38 /var/log/dpkg.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14309 Sep  6 21:29 /var/log/dpkg.log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3260 Aug 25 19:07 /var/log/dpkg.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2341 Jul 20 08:43 /var/log/dpkg.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1602 Jun 26 23:19 /var/log/dpkg.log.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2169 May 27 22:09 /var/log/dpkg.log.5.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    747 Apr 26 13:23 /var/log/dpkg.log.6.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    991 Mar 20  2013 /var/log/dpkg.log.7.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  19268 Mar  9  2013 /var/log/dpkg.log.8.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2268 Jan 29  2013 /var/log/dpkg.log.9.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  12920 Dec  9  2012 /var/log/dpkg.log.10.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  92929 Nov 26  2012 /var/log/dpkg.log.11.gz
```

And then grep through them:

```
$ grep -E "installed.*thunderbird" /var/log/dpkg.log* | head -5    /var/log/dpkg.log:2013-10-06 02:51:40 status installed thunderbird:amd64 1:24.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.10.1
/var/log/dpkg.log:2013-10-06 02:51:40 status installed thunderbird-globalmenu:amd64 1:24.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.10.1
/var/log/dpkg.log:2013-10-06 02:51:40 status installed thunderbird-locale-en:amd64 1:24.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.10.1
/var/log/dpkg.log:2013-10-06 02:51:40 status installed thunderbird-gnome-support:amd64 1:24.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.10.1
/var/log/dpkg.log:2013-10-06 02:51:41 status installed thunderbird-locale-en-us:all 1:24.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.10.1
```

#### Method #2 - .list files

Another technique is to look through the `.list` files that are maintained by `dpkg` which is the workhorse that actually does the package installations under the hood for synaptic and apt.

#### Example

This will show you the last 5 packages installed using this method:

```
$ ls -tl /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list | head -n 5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4261 Oct  6 11:38 /var/lib/dpkg/info/libdirectfb-1.2-9:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    856 Oct  6 11:38 /var/lib/dpkg/info/libts-0.0-0:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    216 Oct  6 11:38 /var/lib/dpkg/info/tsconf.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    263 Oct  6 11:38 /var/lib/dpkg/info/libbluray1:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    290 Oct  6 11:38 /var/lib/dpkg/info/libaacs0:amd64.list
```

You can also look for packages using this method:

```
$ ls -tl /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list | grep thunderbird
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    260 Oct  6 02:47 /var/lib/dpkg/info/thunderbird-locale-en-us.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    187 Oct  6 02:47 /var/lib/dpkg/info/thunderbird-gnome-support.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5041 Oct  6 02:47 /var/lib/dpkg/info/thunderbird.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1148 Oct  6 02:47 /var/lib/dpkg/info/thunderbird-locale-en.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    178 Oct  6 02:47 /var/lib/dpkg/info/thunderbird-globalmenu.list
```

Comment: `ls -tl /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list | grep NAME` is the way! thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ls -lh` in the directory it was installed to (like `/usr/bin`) to see the date. Also, you can use the location where Debian holds packages (can't remember offhand, it's in `/var` somewhere).

Answer (score 1):

If it is a debian package you can use this command.

```
grep install /var/log/dpkg.log
```

Comment: @Fischer An alternative is the log files in `/var/log/apt`. Note that Debian prunes log files by default, so you won't get history for very far back.